# Why can't I install apps to my LG Optimus F3Q's Micro SD?

Tags: applications, external-sd, lg

I got a 32 GB for my LG Optimus F3Q (model number D520) in hopes I'd have more space for apps. I followed this guide:
http://www.howtogeek.com/114667/how-to-install-android-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-move-almost-any-app-to-the-sd-card/

but the suggested command line code didn't work, so I did:

```
adb shell pm set-install-location 2
```

After my get command, it confirmed that everything should be installing to card.

I tried to install Snapchat, and was told I have insufficient space. Same with Yik Yak. I tried moving a few apps to SD card from within my phone's **Settings** → **Apps** option, but only Trivia Crack, Uber, and one other app gave me the option.

So even now I can't figure out how to default app installs to the SD card.
I've consulted quite a few StackOverflow questions in that time, but none of the proposed solutions have helped.

UPDATE: I can move enough things to SD card to install wanted apps, but I still can't install directly to my Micro SD card. What can I do?

Comment: As far as I know, there are 2 SD cards (internal and external). The internal is in `/storage/emulated/x` (Where x can be **0** or **legacy**). Then there is the internal SD card (that you insert) in `/external_sd`. Is there enough space in both?

Comment: If the app doesn't want to be installed in external SD card, it won't be installed there. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html